# Java: make Array and ArrayList of type of Objects stored in an ArrayList (that's passed into the method as parameter)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, arguments, instance

Java:

the relevant problem parts of my method are:

```
public void createArrays(ArrayList<SomeClass> objectList) {
    SomeClass[] array = {objectList.toArray(new SomeClass[objectList.size()])};
    ArrayList<SomeClass> = objectList;
    objectList.get(0).SomeClassInstanceMethod();
}
```

- I have a list of objects of class A and class B.
- Some other class in my project makes these lists, then passes one of the lists into createArrays (to use them for some tasks)
- this method, among other things, creates Array and ArrayList of type SomeClass (which is either A or B) • then, on an element of one array, createArrays calls on an instance method that both A and B have

  I tried many combinations involving getting the class of the 0-index object in the argument ArrayList, but I can never create arrays of a type that's not defined explicitly. How can I do this?

**Clarification**: I'm trying to (1) make arrays of the same type that the argument array has, and I also want to (2) call on an instance method of an element from the array (this creates problems because if I use a superclass, it doesn't call methods that are unique to subclasses like A and B).

**End Goal**: I have a bunch of lists of different class instances ready, and I want to do the exact same procedure on them, so this is why I want to have one method that does the same thing for any list of objects it's passed.

Comment: your question is not clear, what exactly you are trying to achieve ? what is the expected output ?

Comment: This is a simplified version of my much more confusing class, because there's too much context to understand. I'm trying to (1) make arrays of the same type that the argument array has, and I also want to (2) call on an instance method of an element from the array (this creates problems because if I use a superclass, it doesn't call methods that are unique to subclasses like A and B).

Comment: @JohnDoe Post clarifications as edits to your Question rather than as Comments. And discussing your end-goal, your purpose, may elicit a better solution.

Comment: If you are new to object-oriented programming, you may be approaching the problem from the wrong angle. If you want to run the same procedure on instances of different classes, then those objects must have one thing in common: the procedure you want to run. If so, the various classes should all declare that they implement an interface you define as having that particular procedure (method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the `ArrayList` to an `Object` array

```
Object[] objectArr = objectList.toArray();
```

Then if you want to get that elements in the object array back into `SomeClass` check it with `instanceOf` method and cast to `SomeClass` type.

```
if(objectArr[0] instanceOf SomeClass) {
  SomeClass instance = (SomeClass) objectArr[0];
}
```

Or else you can cast the entire object array to a SomeClass array

```
  if (objectArr instanceof SomeClass[]) {
        SomeClass[] instances = (SomeClass[]) objectArr;
}
```

Also, you can try the following approach, by passing the class type as an argument to the `getArray` method.

```
public <T> T getArray(Class<T> type, Object[] objectArr) throws Exception {

    T instances = type.cast(objectArr);
    return instances;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to only do this once? I don't want to repeat the exact same code just to change the name of the class. Maybe have the class as a variable?

Comment: can you try the last method that I posted?

Comment: It highlights the <T> of the Class<T> parameter type, and says "cannot find symbol - class T". It also highlights the declaration statement's T type.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result you want by having `A` and `B` subclasses implement an interface :

```
interface I { 
    void doSomthing(); //the common instance method 
}

class A implements I{

    @Override
    public void doSomthing() {
        System.out.println("A is doing something");
    }
}

class B implements I{

    @Override
    public void doSomthing() {
        System.out.println("B is doing something");
    }
}
```

Invoke `doSomthing()` of all  objectList elements:

```
public static void useList(List<? extends I> objectList) {

    for( I object : objectList) {
        object.doSomthing();
    }
}
```

To create an array of generic type T and size s

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] createArray(Class<T> c, int s) {

    return (T[]) Array.newInstance(c, s);
}
```

Test the above:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create test list 
    List<A> aList = new ArrayList<>();
    aList.add(new A());

    //make array of type A
    I[] array = createArray(aList.get(0).getClass(), aList.size());
    //check array type 
    System.out.println("The class of array is "+ array.getClass());
    //run A.doSomething()
    useList(aList); //output : A is doing something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using an interface to manage the common methods? In this way, class A and class B can implement the the interface and have the common method. You can still access methods unique to either class À or class B by first checking with the instanceOf operator and type casting.

```
interface CommonMethods {
    void method1();

    String commonMethod2(int argument);
} 

    class A implements CommonMethods {
        @Override
        void method1() {
            //write code
        } 
        //override remaining methods and declare other methods unique to class A
    } 

    class B implements CommonMethods {
        @Override
        void method1() {
            //write code
        } 
        //override remaining methods and declare other methods unique to class B
    } 

    //Somewhere in your other class that has the utility method
    public void createArrays(ArrayList<CommonMethods> objectList) {
        CommonMethods[] array = {objectList.toArray(new CommonMethods[objectList.size()])};
        //ArrayList<SomeClass> = objectList;//Consider revising this line. It's an error
        objectList.get(0).method1();//this method is common to A and B

        if (objectList.get(0) instance Of A) {
            A Var = (A) objectList.get(0);
            //call methods unique to A
        } 
    }
```

Good luck

Comment: `objectList.get(0) instance Of A` is not needed because of polymorphism. Also : he implementation of `CommonMethods` need to be public, and `objectList.toArray` needs casting.

Comment: The declaration needs only be public if the implementing classes are in different packages. Also, there is the need for the checking the class to which a CommonMethod belongs in order to call methods specific to that class.

Comment: Invoke `public static void createArrays(List<? extends CommonMethods> objectList) {
  objectList.get(0).method1();
 }`  using `List<A>`  and see that `A.method1()` is invoked. Also the implementation of `CommonMethods` does not compile without `public` accessor, even if it is in the same file.

Comment: This explains that the public accessor is only necessary if the implementing classes are in different packages https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html .Also, as can be seen in the comment attached to the code, the method in the interface can be executed regardless of the specific type of class. Only methods unique to à particular class cannot be executed as such. If your code does not compile without it, you may need to check your package